# Mesh problems Blender3d

Tags: mesh

Combined several objects with Shift + D, then I used solidify. When I'm switching to edit mode, the mesh is completely different from what I need.

1. First image - that's what I need
2. Second image - what I have*

I am a beginner and a lot of difficulties and incomprehensible things arise when I'm working with a mesh

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have some modifiers on your object.  Modifiers take the base mesh and apply a procedure to display a result in real-time, but the base object is actually just what you see in edit mode.

Comment: If you want the final geometry you need to apply the modifiers, this makes them 'real'

Comment: Apart from the other comments, Shift-D is to duplicate objects, not to join them! Ctrl-J joins selected objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the modifier viewable in edit mode. Click the button with the triangle in the modifier tab.

[image]